# Vibration in Android studio

Tags: android, button, design-patterns, vibration

I made different patterns to vibrate the phone when I click a button,I want to vibrate the first pattern then second one ...to n patterns when I write the code it only vibrate the last pattern.. please help me solve this problem

Comment: Just use union pattern

Comment: Post the code so we can tell you what you're doing wrong.